# Change Address STM32F722 Program

Tags: stm32, stm32f7

I'm very inexperienced in `STM32` programming and want to ask about firmware installment with `ST-Link-Utility`.
I've a flight controller that must be flashed with custom firmware.
The firmware provided by developer now is compiled as hex file and has starting address at `0x8008000`.
I need to change it's starting address to `0x2000000`.

Is there any possibilities to do this, without modify source code of the hex file?
What I need to do first in this case?

Comment: 0x8'000'000 is the start of flash memory. Developer places it with 32 KiB offset, probably because he has some bootloader mechanism. 0x20'000'000 is the start of RAM but you can't have any data there permanently. And 0x2'000'000 you have mentioned is an invalid address.

Comment: Where is this requirement of changing the starting address coming from? Developer?

Comment: yes, it's from developer

Comment: Maybe you can share the website of the developer of this custom firmware so we can take a look?

Answer (score 2):

> The firmware provided by developer now is compiled as hex file and has starting address at 0x8008000. I need to change it's starting address to 0x2000000.

This is not possible without recompiling / linking.

For example the controller must know where to find the vector table. And the position is defined somewhere in the hex.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got what you said.
With `ST-Link-Utility` you can easily change offset of `Flash Address` this way:
[image]

Check that and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In this case I need to move then content of the address 0x8000000 to 0x2000000 (sorry, but I don't know if that's possible or not in STM32 programming)

Comment: Let me know. You have a `Hex` file and a STM32 Microcontroller? The tutorial said you have to program the `STM32` from `0x02000000` Address?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: Look at the picture and red aria that I mentioned. After that you opened your `HEX` file you can easily change the value of `Address` field.

Comment: Then select `Target > Connect` and after that select `Target > Program`.

Comment: I got Warning Address out of range

Comment: In addition, I've never changed my Flash Address to 0x02000000 before. I think it's a invalid Address.

Comment: Are you sure the tutorial said that?

Comment: Yes, I got this answer after some discussion.

Comment: Which STM32 Microcontroller do you have?

Comment: It's STM32F722.

Comment: I think your address (0x02000000) is invalid. You have to be sure about that.